# how to plot more than 16 graphics in a raster stack?

Tags: r, plot, stack, raster

I have a Raster Stack with 32 layers, I want to make a plot with some of the layers but the max layers that I can get in the plot is 16 (4 x 4).

```
covs<-stack(NDVI,BTA,biovars)
plot(covs)
```

[image]

I need to insert in the same graph 3 more layers
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `maxnl` parameter to 32 (see the [help](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.8-19/topics/plot) of `plot` in `raster`):

```
plot(covs, maxnl=32)
```

Here is an example:

```
library(raster)
fn <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(fn)
stk <- stack(r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, 
             r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn, r, fn) 
plot(stk, nc=6, maxnl=32)
```

[image]

Comment: It does not solve the problem, I still have 16 graphics. Try with levelplot () but the scales of the graphics are not the same.

Comment: @franciscocorvalan I tested this solution on my PC with 32 layers and it works. Could you share your `covs` object  (or NDVI, BTA, biovars)?

Answer (score 1):

Marco Sadri's solution should work, Can you `show(covs)`?
But you can also do this "manually"

```
par(mfrow=c(6,6))
for (i in 1:nlayers(stk)) {
   plot(stk[[i]])
}
```